# Equivalent of "Error(Err.Number)" VB6 to VB.NET 2022

Tags: string, vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have some VB6 code that needs to be migrated to VB.NET, and I wanted to inquire about this line of code, and see if there is a way to implement it in .NET

```
Error(Err.Number)
```

Keeps telling me that an Expression is expected.

```
If Err.Number = 53 Then
        GoTo x
    Else
        Msg = "      Error N. " & Err.Number & Chr(13) & Error(Err.Number)
        MsgBox(Msg, 16, "Warning")
        FileClose(1)
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VB6 documentation states:

> The return value of the Error function corresponds to the Description
> property of the Err object.

so instead of using `Error(Err.Number)` use `Err.Description`.

Comment: While the above answer is ofc technically correct, you might consider to take advantage of VB.NET's Try/Catch/End Try exception handling instead porting VB6's awkward error handling 1:1 to VB.NET. Especially so, if you consider continuing to develop the application further in VB.NET.